# Equivalent of ScalaCheck for Swift? (Test data generator framework)

Tags: swift, scala, tdd, automated-tests, scalacheck

Is there a good framework available for Xcode/Swift 1.2 that supports automated property based testing? Specifically, something that has a nice framework of Generator-style classes/tools that can create a large number of test values, across a defined range?

Example, I'd like to test email addresses. I'd like to have a class that generates, say, 1,000+ random emails that range from simple ASCII all the way up to complex Unicode, but fitting within the email pattern.

With ScalaCheck this is pretty easy. I haven't found a library that is similar in Swift...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is SwiftCheck https://github.com/typelift/SwiftCheck FWIW, it might be more apropos to ask for the equivalent of **QuickCheck** which is the property-based testing library that originated in Haskell :)

Comment: Perfect... Thank you! :)